# Excel VBA runing automatically when the file is already closed

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file which, when the user opens, should run a function automatically every 30 minutes and close the file.

Specifically, I have the following code under `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
TimeOpened = Now
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("00:30:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("01:00:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("01:30:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("02:00:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("02:30:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
Application.OnTime TimeOpened + TimeValue("03:00:00"), "Check_Average_NA"
End Sub
```

where the function `Check_Average_NA` is saved in `Module1` as

```
Sub Check_Average_NA()

Dim Avg As Double, Na As Long
Dim LastAvgRow As Integer, LastNaRow As Integer, LastTimeRow As Integer


Avg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Missing dates").Range("A1:XFD10000"))
Na = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Missing dates").Range("A1:XFD10000"), "#N/A N/A")

LastAvgRow = Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(1000, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastNaRow = Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(1000, 2).End(xlUp).Row
LastTimeRow = Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(1000, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastAvgRow + 1, 1) = Avg
Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastNaRow + 1, 2) = Na
Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastTimeRow + 1, 3) = Now

If LastAvgRow = 10 And LastNaRow = 10 Then

Else
    If Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastAvgRow, 1) = Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastAvgRow + 1, 1) And Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastNaRow, 2) = Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Input, Average, NA").Cells(LastNaRow + 1, 2) Then
        With Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Worksheets("Missing dates").UsedRange
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Workbooks("Holdings_Pricing - Dec").Save
    Application.Quit
End If

End If
End Sub
```

So what I want to do is to check the average value and count the number of "#N/A N/A" every 30 minutes, record them in the `Input, Average, NA` sheet, and save and close the file if the values are the same as the values recorded 30 minutes ago.

The problem is that.. when I do not need to open this file and therefore it's closed, the file randomly opens itself and tries to run the code. Does anyone know why it happens and how to prevent it?

Thank you.

Comment: An `Application.OnTime` doesn't get cleared when you close the workbook - you need to clear them yourself in your code before closing the workbook.  http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Application.OnTime_en.html

Comment: I see. Is there a way I can clear it in the code without the user (me) editing the code manually every time?

Comment: Yes, of course ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    StartTimer
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    StopTimer
End Sub
```

In a regular module:

```
Const MACRO_NAME As String = "Check_Average_NA"

Dim colTimes As Collection 'global to store scheduled times

Sub StartTimer()
    Dim arrTimes, e, t
    arrTimes = Array("01:00:00", "01:30:00", "02:00:00", "02:30:00", "03:00:00")
    Set colTimes = New Collection
    For Each e In arrTimes
        t = Now + TimeValue(e)
        Application.OnTime t, MACRO_NAME
        colTimes.Add t
    Next e
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    Dim t
    If Not colTimes Is Nothing Then
        For Each t In colTimes
            Application.OnTime t, MACRO_NAME, schedule:=False '<< cancel the timer
        Next t
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Do you know when the parameter "Cancel" in the Workbook_BeforeClose is provided?

Comment: It's there so (for example) you can cancel the close if some specific validation step fails and you want the user to make some changes before closing.

Comment: I see. Thank you. 

Whenever I try to close the file, it says Run-time error '1004': Method 'OnTime' of object'_Application' failed.

When I click debug, it brings me to the "Application.OnTime t, MACRO_NAME, schedule:=False" line of StopTimer. Do you know why?

Comment: If that timer has already run you may get an error when you try to cancel it.  I would maybe wrap the line which is erroring in `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: I will use On Error Reume Next. Thank you so much !